# Can not load custom font file `.otf` in Laravel-dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf, export-to-pdf

Currently I use `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` for export pdf in Laravel 5.6, but I have problem about load custom font file.

I can load font file had extension is `.ttf` by `php load_font.php`, it work perfect.

But I can not use font file with extension is `.otf`, the `load_font.php` can work with this extension but can not use when export pdf.

What did I wrong here, how can I embedded a font file with format is `.otf` when export PDF? I hope somebody had experience about this problem. Can you help me? thank you so much.

Comment: DOMPDF doesn't support .otf so you cant do this. Only solution is to either use a .ttf variant or use a different PDF library that supports .otf.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I see, but I only know library `dompdf` or `tcpdf`, but both of them not support `otf` file too. Could you suggest me some other library?@Loek

Comment: I thought TCPDF had at least partial support? You could try [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) which has support for Type1 fonts. According to this [question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83320/what-is-the-difference-between-truetype-fonts-and-type-1-fonts) you should be able to find your .otf font as a Type1 font somewhere. Personally, I would really just use a good substitute .ttf font since this will cost you so much time that I can't imagine being worth it.

Comment: Thank for your answer, But in my case I have to use `.otf` file because this is font file from my customer, I can not change it. This font file is not free. I don't have other way.@Loek

Comment: Good luck then! If you found out how it can be done, would you be so kind to post as an answer? Would be very interested in it :)

Comment: What does "can no use" mean exactly? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 1):

What about trying to convert **.otf** to **.ttf** format? 
I think that is the optimal way for your problem.

otf to ttf converter sites, 
https://convertio.co/otf-ttf/ 
https://everythingfonts.com/otf-to-ttf 
https://anyconv.com/otf-to-ttf-converter/